# mentioning interpolation method in cv2.warpaffine()

Tags: python, image, opencv

How can I use the bicubic interpolation method in the `cv2.warpAffine()` method? I am trying to rotate an image through a non-center point.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)
rows,cols = img.shape
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-40,1) 
dst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows),flags=CV_INTER_CUBIC)
#cv2.Resize(src, dst, interpolation=CV_INTER_CUBIC)
plt.imshow(dst)
```

With this I get `NameError: name 'CV_INTER_CUBIC' is not defined`

Comment: check the flags of warpaffine in this [link.](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html)

Comment: I have tried already to use it . I get the following error


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'

I understand there are other pages with the same questions. I have tried them too but still doesnt get me running :( I have been on the for the last 10 days !

Comment: Can you please post a [minimum verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? You should be using `cv2`, not `cv`. The constant should be `cv2.INTER_BICUBIC`.

Comment: As mentioned below and in the comments, it's `cv2.INTER_CUBIC` not `cv2.INTER_BICUBIC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most* of the constants in OpenCV that have a prepending `CV_` have them removed in the newer versions and they just become `CONSTANT_VALUE` instead of `CV_CONSTANT_VALUE`. For example, when you're changing colorspace from BGR to HSV, you use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` instead of `cv2.CV_COLOR_BGR2HSV` which you would use in C++. However even for C++ the constants for interpolation methods have had the prepending `CV_` removed, so it's also `INTER_CUBIC` and not `CV_INTER_CUBIC` (although the latter is still defined). See for e.g. the [docs for `resize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize) which the docs for `warpAffine()` reference for the interpolation methods.

The basic separation is that the `CV_` constants come from the original C API. You can see all the C API constants definitions [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/df/d4e/group__imgproc__c.html). And you can see how the prepending `CV_` was removed from the constants in the newer API by browsing through the documentation, like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html) for e.g.

So anyways, the answer to the question is to use the flag `cv2.INTER_CUBIC`.

Comment: Just a little comment. 
CV2.INTER_BICUBIC doest exist. It is simply cv2.INTER_CUBIC

Comment: Oops. Thanks for that, I even kept writing `INTER_CUBIC` when I was typing that but thought I was screwing it up!